# Button mnemonics and i18n

Tags: internationalization, mnemonics

Just a quick UI-style question here: Is it a good idea to internationalize button mnemonics? E.g. if my "Next" button has the mnemonic "N" in English, should it be "S" for "Suivant" in French? Or should I keep them the same so that keyboard combinations work across languages?

How do the big players (Windows, Mac, ...) do it?

Thanks for some advice and kind regards

Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at least in Windows, Microsoft is internationalizing them. That's good enough for me, in any event.